# Preview the form details in popup using php with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add the popup for the preview button. When user clicks on the preview button, the validation for the form as well as popup with the details should be displayed. If the field is blank the requird field should be displayed and then once the user enter all the details pop up as to be displayed. In my code both popup and required both works together when user clicks the preview button.

Here is the code.

```
  <form method="post" align="center" action="">
                                <div class="login">
                                    <div class="login-form">
                                        <h3>Title:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" required="required" /><br />
                                        <h3>Image:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" name="image"  required="required"/>
                                        <br />
                                        <h3>Date:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" id="filter-date" name="date"  required="required"/>
                                        <br />
                                        <h3>Description:</h3> 
                                        <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="description" type="text"  required="required">
                                        </textarea>
                                        <br />

                                        <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>


                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: You need to use ajax for this. Are you familiar with PHP?

Comment: yes i know php. not so familar with ajax

Comment: Is Open Modal used as preview button?

Comment: yes it is used as a preview button

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
        //----- OPEN
        $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {

            if ($('input:text[name="title"]').val().length == 0 || $('input:text[name="image"]').val().length == 0 || $('input:text[name="date"]').val().length == 0 || !$.trim($("textarea").val())) {
               alert('Fill all the fields');
               return false;
            }else {
                var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
                $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        //----- CLOSE
        $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
            var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

```css
   /* Outer */
        .popup {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:none;
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }

        /* Inner */
        .popup-inner {
            max-width:700px;
            width:90%;
            padding:40px;
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            border-radius:3px;
            background:#fff;
        }

        /* Close Button */
        .popup-close {
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            padding-top:4px;
            display:inline-block;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            right:0px;
            transition:ease 0.25s all;
            -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
            transform:translate(50%, -50%);
            border-radius:1000px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
            font-size:20px;
            text-align:center;
            line-height:100%;
            color:#fff;
        }

        .popup-close:hover {
            -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
            transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
            background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
            text-decoration:none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" align="center" action="">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-form">
            <h3>Title:</h3>
            <input type="text" name="title" required="required" /><br />
            <h3>Image:</h3>
            <input type="text" name="image"  required="required"/>
            <br />
            <h3>Date:</h3>
            <input type="text" id="filter-date" name="date"  required="required"/>
            <br />
            <h3>Description:</h3>
            <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="description"  required="required">
                                        </textarea>
            <br />

            <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">  <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button></a>


        </div>
    </div>

</form>


<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
        </div>
        <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
    $(function() {
        //----- OPEN
        $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
            var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

            e.preventDefault();
        });

        //----- CLOSE
        $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
            var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

```css
 /* Outer */
        .popup {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:none;
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }

        /* Inner */
        .popup-inner {
            max-width:700px;
            width:90%;
            padding:40px;
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            border-radius:3px;
            background:#fff;
        }

        /* Close Button */
        .popup-close {
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            padding-top:4px;
            display:inline-block;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            right:0px;
            transition:ease 0.25s all;
            -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
            transform:translate(50%, -50%);
            border-radius:1000px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
            font-size:20px;
            text-align:center;
            line-height:100%;
            color:#fff;
        }

        .popup-close:hover {
            -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
            transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
            background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
            text-decoration:none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" align="center" action="">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-form">
            <h3>Title:</h3>
            <input type="text" name="title" required="required" /><br />
            <h3>Image:</h3>
            <input type="text" name="image"  required="required"/>
            <br />
            <h3>Date:</h3>
            <input type="text" id="filter-date" name="date"  required="required"/>
            <br />
            <h3>Description:</h3>
            <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="description" type="text"  required="required">
                                        </textarea>
            <br />

            <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">  <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button></a>


        </div>
    </div>

</form>


<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
        </div>
        <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually when the field is empty the I want to display required field if all the details are entered I want popup should be displayed with the details

Comment: do u want empty field validation for your form?

Comment: do u want required field validation for textarea?

Comment: got it checkout the answer below

Comment: remove your previous script and update my new script

Answer (score 2):

```js
 $(function() {
        //----- OPEN
        $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {

            if ($('input:text[name="title"]').val().length == 0 || $('input:text[name="image"]').val().length == 0 || $('input:text[name="date"]').val().length == 0 || !$.trim($("textarea").val())) {
               alert('Fill all the fields');
               return false;
            }else {
                var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
                $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        //----- CLOSE
        $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
            var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
            $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

```css
  /* Outer */
        .popup {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:none;
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }

        /* Inner */
        .popup-inner {
            max-width:700px;
            width:90%;
            padding:40px;
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%;
            -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            border-radius:3px;
            background:#fff;
        }

        /* Close Button */
        .popup-close {
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            padding-top:4px;
            display:inline-block;
            position:absolute;
            top:0px;
            right:0px;
            transition:ease 0.25s all;
            -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
            transform:translate(50%, -50%);
            border-radius:1000px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
            font-size:20px;
            text-align:center;
            line-height:100%;
            color:#fff;
        }

        .popup-close:hover {
            -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
            transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
            background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
            text-decoration:none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" align="center" action="">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-form">
            <h3>Title:</h3>
            <input type="text" name="title" required="required" /><br />
            <h3>Image:</h3>
            <input type="text" name="image"  required="required"/>
            <br />
            <h3>Date:</h3>
            <input type="text" id="filter-date" name="date"  required="required"/>
            <br />
            <h3>Description:</h3>
            <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="description"  required="required">
                                        </textarea>
            <br />

            <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">  <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button></a>


        </div>
    </div>

</form>


<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
        </div>
        <p><a data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` to the form *myFrm*
Here it is the ajax code::

You have to mention the URL to respective file on which you write your respective validation code...

```
<script>
    jQuery('#myBtn').click(function(){
        var data = jQuery('form#myFrm').serialize();
        jQuery.ajax(function(){
            data: data,
            url: '<url path to php file>',
            method: 'post',
            success: function(res){
                jQuery('.modal-content-inner').html(res);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Updated Your Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-content-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $title = $('#title')
  var $image = $('#image')
  var $filterDate = $('#filterDate')
  var $description = $('#description')
  
  $('#myForm').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // some other code
    // maybe disabling submit button
    // then:
   // $(form).submit();
   $('.title').text($title.val())
   $('.image').text($image.val())
   $('.filterDate').text($filterDate.val())
   $('.description').text($description.val())
   $( ".modalDialog" ).dialog();
  }
  });
  
  
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form method="post" align="center" id="myForm">
                                <div class="login">
                                    <div class="login-form">
                                        <h3>Title:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" required/><br />
                                        <h3>Image:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" name="image" id="image"  required/>
                                        <br />
                                        <h3>Date:</h3>
                                        <input type="text" id="filterDate" name="date"  required/>
                                        <br />
                                        <h3>Description:</h3> 
                                        <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="description" id="description" required>
                                        </textarea>
                                        <br />

                                        <button type="submit" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>



                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                            
<div class="modalDialog" title="Preview" style="display:none;">
  <p>Title : <span class="title"></span></p>
  <p>Image :<span class="image"></span></p>
  <p>Date : <span class="filterDate"></span></p>
  <p>description : <span class="description"></span></p>
  
</div>
```